Don't understand the definition of linked at infinity
I am readind the book of  Farb-Margalit "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups" (but I think it is a general definition) and I have a question on the definition of "Linked at infinity". Recall that the axis of a hyperbolic isometry $\gamma$ has two endpoints lying on $\partial \mathbb{H}^{2}$. We say that two hyperbolic isometries $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are linked at infinity if the endpoints of the axis of $\gamma$ are linked with the endpoints of the axis of $\delta$ in $\partial \mathbb{H}^{2}$, that is the endpoints of the axis of $\gamma$ separate the endpoints of the axis of $\delta$.
My questions are: saying that $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are linked at infinity is equivalent to saying that their axes have a point of intersection in $\mathbb{H}^{2}$? If the axes of $\gamma$ and $\delta$ share a common endpoint in $\mathbb{H}^{2}$, we can talk of these two isometries being linked at infinity?

Yes and no.....
